# Find specific table using BeautifulSoup with specific caption

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to locate the specific table below in the given HTML:

```
<table class="sidearm-table collapse-on-medium accordion" accordion-table="" sortable-table="">
                        <caption>Tennessee Tech<span class="hide"> - Pitching Stats</span></caption>
```

My approach was to find the caption, then proceed to find the parent table, from which I will iterate through the rows to find my desired text (I can accomplish this part on my own). I believe my error is buried in the fact that the caption text continues into the span tag, however not sure if this is the case. My code to do so is given below, however it continues to return None because it cannot locate the table (something with my syntax is likely incorrect):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}

redirect = requests.get('http://goblueraiders.com/boxscore.aspx?path=baseball&id=6117', headers = header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(redirect, 'html.parser')

test = soup.find('caption', text = 'Tennessee Tech').find_parent('table', {'class': 'sidearm-table collapse-on-medium accordion'})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to find all captions and then to match the caption text like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests


header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}

redirect = requests.get('http://goblueraiders.com/boxscore.aspx?path=baseball&id=6117', headers = header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(redirect, 'html.parser')

for caption in soup.find_all('caption'):
    if caption.get_text() == 'Tennessee Tech - Pitching Stats':
        table = caption.find_parent('table', {'class': 'sidearm-table collapse-on-medium accordion'})
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of approaching it this way! Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<table class="sidearm-table collapse-on-medium accordion" accordion-table="" sortable-table="">
<caption>
Tennessee Tech
<span class="hide"> - Pitching Stats</span>
</caption>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'sidearm-table'})

print(table.contents)
```

Output:

```
['\n', <caption>
Tennessee Tech
<span class="hide"> - Pitching Stats</span>
</caption>, '\n']
```

But your URL is not found (timeout) :

`http://goblueraiders.com/boxscore.aspx?path=baseball&id=6117`

Comment: This will only work if the first table found corresponds to the one I am looking for... It does not identify the caption text at all

Comment: Put a complete example ;), I think there is another mean to identify your table with this `caption` it is not tricky.